# Bootstrap integration into PHP(CodeIgniter) - Setup?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

The results I get when I google are a bit outdated. How should I integrate the SB Admin 2 bootstrap theme into the PHP framework codeigniter?

From a more noob perspective, how would I set up the server environment to test it out locally? XAMPP does not appear to work for me on Lubuntu 14.04(LXDE), Apache server never starts up.

I use PHPStorm as my IDE.

Sorry for the beginner question, but I've started over on this project 5 times now because things mess up.

Comment: For your linux question I would go with Vagrant (https://www.vagrantup.com/) this works like a virtual machine on your computer so you can have a complete environment you can change and is standard

Comment: I use crouton for a lubuntu distro on my chromebook. Running virtualbox would not be good for my ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial can get help you to setup the environment,
apache is included in this php package

http://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/